# Unicode characters in Ruby 1.9.3 IRB with RVM

Tags: ruby, unicode, osx-lion, rvm, irb

**Update**: I found almost exact [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4590725/80851), yet it has slightly different prerequisites and thus doesn't help much.

Given:

- **MacOS Lion 10.7.3**
- **rvm 1.14.2**
- **ruby 1.9.3p194** (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

  Ruby was installed with the following line:

  `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/`

When I fire up `irb` or `rails c` and start typing unicode characters, I get:

`\U+FFD0\U+FFBF\U+FFD1\U+FFD0\U+FFB8\U+FFD0\U+FFBC\U+FFD0\U+FFB5\U+FFD1`

**How do I get unicode characters displayed correctly when typing on Ruby/Rails consoles?**

P.S. Typing same characters in bash session of Terminal result in proper output.

P.P.S. Just to be clear -- in console I am typing russian characters: are they considered unicode symbols?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RVM has [issues](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1016) with readline installed via homebrew. [This](https://gist.github.com/1968562) gist worked perfectly for me:

```
$ rvm get latest
$ rvm pkg install readline
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Instead of `install` you can use `reinstall`.

Comment: That worked for me, even without the --with-readline-dir option. The "pkg install" part seems to be what does it.

Answer (score 3):

only `rvm reinstall all --force` helped me

Answer (score 0):

Other solution would be using http://railsinstaller.org it already provides everything compiled for Ruby and Rails, I was working hard to solve all the libraries compilation and provide one package.