# How do I fix an invalid multibyte character in regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ascii

I have a regex:

```
/[!,.!:;\-\?\(\)"\s\n]/
```

Which works fine, but when I add:

```
«»
```

to the regex it causes an error:

```
invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

What is wrong? How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you testing this in irb or within a ruby file?

irb installations can have problems with unicode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590725/how-can-i-input-multibyte-characters-in-rails-console-or-irb

Comment: Try using the UTF-8 values: « = \xC2\xAB, » = \xC2\xBB

Comment: pje, it's rails, server fails to start with this error

Answer (score 2):

On the first line of your file, write

```
#encoding: UTF-8
```

This is needed for ruby 1.9, but not for1.8 or 2.0

Comment: @pguardiario Well, yeah. Otherwise you need to set the correct encoding. But IMHO, with few exceptions, if you aren't using UTF-8, you should

Comment: That may be, but unless the document is encoded UTF-8, this will be a problem.